Where can I post / engage with the community regarding 'for fun' projects
I have been working on a 'for fun' crypto project and I wanted to share it with the community for input and discussion.  It's fairly open-ended, so not a good fit for here.  
Where and how can i share it with the community?

If you have specific, concrete, answerable questions about it, you can ask on the main site.
If you "just" want to share it and maybe discuss with anybody who read it, you can do so in our chat: The Side Channel. But please don't go overboard with it.

Generally
For a general case SEJPM already wrote a good answer.
I'ld merely like to add that you should please note our help center states 

If you want peer review of your full cryptographic scheme, here is not the place to acquire it. However, you might like to break your problem down into specifics, such as "under these conditions, does structure X have desired security property Y?" which would be a perfect fit for us.

which somewhat underlines SEJPM's 

_please don't go overboard with it.

For anything else, our chat is indeed the best place to share stuff.
Your Specific Case
Having looked at your project, it doesn't seem as if you'ld be having any trouble or problems with it where we can help… at least from what I've been quick-reading. Seems fun indeed and I'ld dive into it at a later time this week if only I could find a link to download the source and/or binary (chances are my quick-reading made me miss it, so a little heads-up would help).
Anyway, wrapping it up I can only echo what SEJPM already hinted at: sharing it at The Side Channel is the way to go for your specific case.
